# getting the active alarms for specific host generated in zabbix when there is fault using zabbix api

Tags: python-2.7, zabbix

I am trying to create script using python to popup window when there is an active alarm on specific switch port. I am using zabbix as snmp system and I am using zabbix api in python. until now I was able to retrieve the alarms by getting the triggers for specific host by:

```
host = zapi.trigger.get({"host": "SW-1", "only_true": "extend"})
```

this will return the following:

```
[{u'status': u'0',
  u'description': u'{HOST.NAME}  GigabitEthernet0/36 down',
  u'state': u'0',
  u'url': u'',
  u'type': u'0',
  u'templateid': u'0',
  u'lastchange': u'1466402478',
  u'value': u'1',
  u'priority': u'4',
  u'triggerid': u'13914',
  u'flags': u'4',
  u'comments': u'',
  u'error': u'',
  u'expression': u'{13644}=2 and {13645}=2'},
```

The problem is I am not able to see if the status of the alarm is **OK** or **Problem** as it shows in the web page of zabbix for me to track it and launch my popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM/OK is identified by the [value](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/trigger/object) property - in your example it's set to 1, so that trigger is in the problem state.

The `trigger.get` API documentation page has [an example to retrieve only triggers in the problem state](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/trigger/get#retrieving_triggers_in_problem_state).

Comment: Thanks for this information. its working fine for me